# How to have custom array of numbers as values in react Material UI slider?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, range, slider

I'm using Material UI slider as range between numbers [1,2,5,6,7,8]. The problem is that I cant have those number showing on the slider as they are, it will show numbers from 1-8 but doesn't show the labels of 3 and 4.
[image]

To explain more here is an example:-
My data looks something like this [1,2,5,6,7,8]
my marks on the slider is [{44:1},{45:2},{46:5},{47:6},{48:7},{49:8}]

I want the slider to show the labels and array as matched but since the slider takes the value as array of two numbers [1,8] , its will render all numbers starting from 1 until 8. Yes I can skip the values from 3 and 4, but the slider looks bad with that gap.

Comment: Can you edit the question and show us what you have done till now

Comment: Provide code, I think this is posible with styling only.